# Simple jMeter non gui test ends with Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am trying to run the simple jMeter test in non gui, I am using a simple command like:

```
jmeter -n -t davelatal-cz.jmx -Jusers=4 -Jduration=300
```

I changed thread preferences as you can see on screenshot below:
[Thread Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Xs9.png)

So if I try to run this simple HTTP Request test, bash shows me this error:

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Screenshot:

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGNiE.png)

Here is LOG file:

```
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to cs_CZ 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 ERROR - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Could not find resources for 'cs_CZ' 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /usr/share/jmeter/bin/user.properties 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /usr/share/jmeter/bin/system.properties 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Setting JMeter property: users=4 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Setting JMeter property: duration=300 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2014 The Apache Software Foundation 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.11.20151206 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_131 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Linux 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=4.4.0-43-Microsoft 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=čeština (Česká republika) 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=čeština (Česká republika) 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=/usr/share/jmeter 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =/mnt/c/Users/latal/Documents/Nigga 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =/mnt/c/Users/latal/Documents/Nigga 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 127.0.1.1 Name: J5MPJ72 FullName: J5MPJ72.bscpraha.cz 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='/mnt/c/Users/latal/Documents/Nigga' 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/mnt/c/Users/latal/Documents/Nigga' 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading file: davelatal-cz.jmx 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.6 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file version 1554411 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration' : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
---- Debugging information ----
message             : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.MissingFieldException
cause-message       : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
class               : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.SampleSaveConfigurationConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/ResultCollector/objProp/value/sentBytes
line number         : 56
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.ObjectProperty
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector
converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
class[3]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[3]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
------------------------------- : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration' : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
---- Debugging information ----
message             : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.MissingFieldException
cause-message       : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
class               : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.SampleSaveConfigurationConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/ResultCollector/objProp/value/sentBytes
line number         : 56
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.ObjectProperty
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector
converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
class[3]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[3]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
-------------------------------
message             : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration' : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
---- Debugging information ----
message             : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.MissingFieldException
cause-message       : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
class               : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.SampleSaveConfigurationConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/ResultCollector/objProp/value/sentBytes
line number         : 56
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.ObjectProperty
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2]            : org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector
converter-type[2]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter
class[3]            : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type[3]   : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration' : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.TestElementConverter.unmarshal(TestElementConverter.java:107)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/ResultCollector/objProp/value/sentBytes
line number         : 56
version             : 2.11.20151206
------------------------------- 
2017/09/19 08:05:15 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:92)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:755)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:733)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:392)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)
```

I already tried to change project folder, google it but I'm at the end of the options. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Or where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you save the jmx using Jmeter 3.1 or before?

Comment: Nope I using Jmeter 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are running a test which is created using a newer JMeter version on JMeter 2.11 so my expectation is that you need to upgrade your JMeter.

Current JMeter release is [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32).

You can always get the latest JMeter version from [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page.

---

So I would recommend switching from JMeter which you seem to be getting from your Linux distribution repositories to the binary bundle you can download directly from Apache. Just pull the tarball, unpack it somewhere and run JMeter from this folder. Make sure you're running Jmeter as `./jmeter` or add it to your [system PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) before the one which is from the repositories.

Comment: Ouch so I checked my version and it is v3.2  so I will try check the path